# log4Net RollingFileAppender Does Not "Roll"

Tags: c#, logging, log4net, error-logging

I am using log4Net to capture transaction data from an application, to help with debugging issues/errors basically.  Lately, it hasn't been creating new files after the file size hits 10MB, it just stops recording data. I looked online and found a source saying I needed to added a MutexLock, so I did and nothing changed.  My appender and root level sections are below:

```
<!-- Appenders section -->
<log4net>
  <appender name="file" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="c:\programs\DocIt\production\documakerError.log"/>
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
    <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff} [%thread] %-5p %c - %m%n"  />
    </layout>
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MutexLock" />
  </appender>
<!-- root section -->
<root>
  <level value="DEBUG"/>
  <appender-ref ref="file" />
</root>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: it is due to you have set its limit in configuration `<maximumFileSize value="10MB" />`

Comment: From what I understand with log4Net, the maximumFileSize is the size the file will reach before it creates another file (in the rollingFileAppender).

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this config, it matches mine almost verbatim (other than the locking model you added and mine is 4096KB size)

Comment: Do you know of any other issues/reasons with log4Net, that it wouldn't create the rolling files?

Comment: Perhaps a permissions issue? Does it have ability to create files in that folder?

Comment: It does.  I can delete the one file there, and it will create another file.  It just won't create the rolling files.

Comment: Crystal ball says that it works just fine, you just can't find the files back.  We can't tell what [location of my file] might be, the one detail you obfuscated that truly matters.  Environment.CurrentDirectory is the worst possible global variable.

Comment: The path of the file is a folder path on the C drive of the server.  I'll edit the question to have the actual value in there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the reason why I was not able to get log4Net to roll the files.  It appears that **the Modify permission on the file share was revoked** from our service account.  This allowed the service account to create new files, but wasn't able to rename them; which is crucial for the RollingFileAppender.